# Jupyter notebook not creating config files in the specified directories

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I run `jupyter notebook` I get: `Your file couldn’t be accessed It may have been moved, edited or deleted` in chrome.

I checked `jupyter --path` and looked at the directories listed and most of them don't exist, I tried reinstalling and I'm getting the same issue.

I manually copied the url with the token and I was able to run jupyter notebook but I can't find the config, data or runtime.

Edit: I previously installed iJava but didn't reinstall but it appears when I run jupyter notebook making me think it didn't uninstall properly. Not sure how else to uninstall it considering I can't find the installation path.